# Boolean Toggle in Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, boolean, nested-resources

I have a `Issues` Controller and a nested `Comments` Controller. My *Comments form* is in my *Issues Show View*.

I'm trying to add a checkbox when commenting that would toggle the `:closed => boolean` attribute on my `Issue`.

```
<%= form_for @issue.comments.build, url: script_issue_comments_path(@script, @issue) do |f| %>

<!-- Form , etc-->

<%= form_for [@script, @issue] do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :closed %> Mark as Closed
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

That obviously didn't work. How can achieve this ?

Basically i will put the checkbox right next to the submit button of the Comment.. So if selected, the Issue attribute `:closed` will be set to `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner form you have there isn't a nested form (in rails terms), and as you've found won't behave in the way you're wanting because it's not really tied to the submission of the outer form.

One approach you could do, which would keep the comments controller from having responsibility of editing issues at the same time (which would be messy in my opinion), would be to have something like a `comment_closes_issue` attribute on the comment. Then, when you save the comment, if `comment_closes_issue` is true, then update the parent issue... It's still blurring the lines between the two models a little, but if they're closely tied, then perhaps that's ok in your application.

Edit - here's an example of how to handle that, assuming a Comment belongs to an Issue:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue

  after_save :close_parent_issue, if: :comment_closes_issue

  private

  def close_parent_issue
    issue.update_attributes closed: true
  end
end
```

Then in your view, you can just have `<%= f.checkbox :comment_closes_issue %>...`

Comment: That sounds well, Could you update your answer on `How` to code this (First time encountering this kind of problem).

Comment: @TheMiniJohn Sure. I've added an example which makes some assumptions about the way your models are structured. Hope it helps.